# Removing all line spacing from a flextable using flextable and officer packages in R

Tags: r, flextable, officer, line-spacing

How do you remove all line spacing in a flextable when creating a flextable using the flextable package and printing it into a powerpoint document using the officer package in R?

By default it appears to have line spacing 1.0 with spacing 2 pt before and 2 pt after. How do I get it so I have spacing 0 pt before and 0 pt after?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use function `padding` for that:

```
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

flextable(head(iris)) %>% 
  padding(padding = 0, part = "all") %>% 
  autofit() %>% 
  print(preview = "pptx")
```